# Laravel query help needed

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have a question about Laravel queries, so I have a upload Model and database table which stores all my images. Then there is an Activity Model and database table which stores all my activities. For each activity I want a image.

So my Activity model has a 'uploads_id' column. I wrote the query like this:

```
$activity_images =  DB::table('uploads')
->join('activities', 'uploads.id', '=', 'activities.upload_id')
->where('uploads.id', '=', 'activities.upload_id')
->get();
```

It cannot find the right image what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are "joining" twice in your `join` and `where` clause. You connect uploads.id and activities.upload_id one time in the `join` and again in the `where` clause.

If you want to query for a special upload.id, your query should look like this:

```
$activity_images =  DB::table('uploads')
->join('activities', 'uploads.id', '=', 'activities.upload_id')
->where('uploads.id', '=', '<yourUploadID>')
->get();
```

If you want all images, you can delete the `where` statement.

```
$activity_images =  DB::table('uploads')
->join('activities', 'uploads.id', '=', 'activities.upload_id')
->get();
```

If you use `join` an `inner join` will be used. 
You could also use `leftJoin` if you want all entries from the table uploads.

```
$activity_images =  DB::table('uploads')
->leftJoin('activities', 'uploads.id', '=', 'activities.upload_id')
->get();
```

Does it solve your issue?

Comment: The second suggestion solved my problem thank you. I was already passing the $id of the Activity through the URL but I added a second one for the upload_id. Strange URL now but it works.